# How to kill headless X server started via Python?

Tags: python, screenshot, xserver

I want to get screenshots of a webpage in Python. For this I am using http://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png/ .

```
    newArgs = ["xvfb-run", "--server-args=-screen 0, 640x480x24", sys.argv[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
        if sys.argv[i] not in ["-x", "--xvfb"]:
            newArgs.append(sys.argv[i])
    logging.debug("Executing %s" % " ".join(newArgs))
    os.execvp(newArgs[0], newArgs)
```

Basically calls xvfb-run with the correct args. But `man xvfb` says:

`Note that the demo X clients used in the above examples will not exit on their own, so they will have to be killed before xvfb-run will exit.`

So that means that this script will <????> if this whole thing is in a loop, (To get multiple screenshots) unless the X server is killed. How can I do that?

Comment: webkit2png.py should exit after taking screenshot, no need to kill it.

Comment: Yes, but if I am looping within the webkit2png.py, it wont die itself.

Comment: What is the reason to used endless (`while True`) loop instead of just several iteration (`for i in range(n)`) or `break` when some time passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`os.execvp`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.html#os.execvp)  states:

> These functions all execute a new
>   program, replacing the current
>   process; they do not return. [..]

So after calling `os.execvp` no other statement in the program will be executed. You may want to use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead:

> The `subprocess` module allows you to
>   spawn new processes, connect to their
>   input/output/error pipes, and obtain
>   their return codes. This module
>   intends to replace several other,
>   older modules and functions, such as:

Using `subprocess.Popen`, the code to run `xlogo` in the virtual framebuffer X server becomes:

```
import subprocess
xvfb_args = ['xvfb-run', '--server-args=-screen 0, 640x480x24', 'xlogo']
process = subprocess.Popen(xvfb_args)
```

Now the problem is that `xvfb-run` launches `Xvfb` in a background process. Calling `process.kill()` will not kill `Xvfb` (at least not on my machine...). I have been fiddling around with this a bit, and so far the only thing that works for me is:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

SERVER_NUM = 99  # 99 is the default used by xvfb-run; you can leave this out.

xvfb_args = ['xvfb-run', '--server-num=%d' % SERVER_NUM,
             '--server-args=-screen 0, 640x480x24', 'xlogo']
subprocess.Popen(xvfb_args)

# ... do whatever you want to do here...

pid = int(open('/tmp/.X%s-lock' % SERVER_NUM).read().strip())
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

So this code reads the process ID of `Xvfb` from `/tmp/.X99-lock` and sends the process an interrupt. It works, but does yield an error message every now and then (I suppose you can ignore it, though). Hopefully somebody else can provide a more elegant solution. Cheers.