# How do I use python-webkit2png to take many screenshots at the same time?

Tags: python, screenshot, xserver

I've got thousands of urls from many hosts I need to screenshot.

I can use the lib fine from the command line, but how can I integrate it into my code so I can take multiple screenshots simultaneously?

I think it's something to do with xvfb as with the answer to this question: [How to kill headless X server started via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747022/how-to-kill-headless-x-server-started-via-python) but I'm not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 2):

here I have used an argument to pass a location of .txt, which contains a list of site(newline delimited), and the second argument for the location of output PNG file.

https://gist.github.com/deadstar1/e8d30102afbaefec531d6708f761e104
thanks to @paljenczy

Answer (score 1):

I used `subprocess` to call `webkit2png` (which was installed through `python-webkit2png`),
it worked fine.

```
def scrape_url(url, outpath):
    """
    Requires webkit2png to be on the path
    """
    subprocess.call(["webkit2png", "-o", outpath, "-g", "1000", "1260",
                     "-t", "30", url])

def scrape_list_urls(list_url_out_name, outdir):
    """
    list_url_out_name is a list of tuples: (url, name)
    where name.png will be the image's name
    """
    count = 0
    for url, name in list_url_out_name:
        print count
        count += 1
        outpath = outdir + name + '.png'
        scrape_url(url, outpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this (untested):

```
from webkit2png import WebkitRenderer, init_qtgui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

def renderer_func():   
    renderer = WebkitRenderer()
    renderer.width = 800
    renderer.height = 600
    renderer.timeout = 10
    renderer.wait = 1
    renderer.format = "png"
    renderer.grabWholeWindow = False

    outfile = open("stackoverflow.png", "w")
    renderer.render_to_file(url="http://stackoverflow.com", file=outfile)
    outfile.close()

app = init_qtgui()
QTimer.singleShot(0, renderer_func)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This was shamelessly ripped off from the [source code of webkit2png.py](http://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png/blob/master/webkit2png.py).

Comment: Thanks, but the part that I am having trouble with is using Xvfb